# Server Sent Event HTML5 error(the resource from this url is not text)

Tags: java, html, servlets

I wrote this Servlet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
    ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");

    PrintWriter printWriter=response.getWriter();
    printWriter.write("Hello!");
}
```

and also this java script in index.jsp:

```
<script>
    var resource = new EventSource("/servlet");
    resource.onmessage = function (e) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = e.data;
    }
</script>
```

in order to create demo on server-sent events in html5. I inspected the jsp page in firefox and I got this error: `the resource from this url is not text` and nothing shows up. by the way request status is 200, OK. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the response header

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
```

Comment: by that, no connection will be established.

Comment: @SuperHornet Which connection ? What is the relation between ContentType and connection ??

Comment: contentType must be set to text/event-stream

Comment: @SuperHornet can you please check by removing charset

Comment: @SuperHornet  Can you please try in another browser ? Suspecting the browser not supporting HTML5 ?